# Key to "Find Next" in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> on google docs, it lets me search the first occurrence of the string I enter, and it informs me about how many appearances of the string there are.

But What key(s) can I use to move to the next appearance? If I press <kbd>F3</kbd> then the browser search functionality is triggered (at least using Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: I didn't. And it works! Thanks :-)

Comment: Also worthy to mention that F3 works if you first click somewhere in the document before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) is the dedicated shortcut for this.

[Source](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/179738?hl=en).

Comment: This works only while the search input box is still open. Do you know a way to find-next after escaping out of it? Or at least to move focus to the page while searching - e.g. so you can make quick edits at each location. I find I have to keep using ⌘+F, esc, <edit>, ⌘+F, enter, esc, <edit>, ⌘+F, enter, esc, <edit>...

Comment: I wished it would be F3 instead...